# How can a send data from NextJS api server with webhook to frontend without socketio?

Tags: next.js, websocket, socket.io, webhooks, ws

I already try to use socket io, but is just too overengineer to my propus.

I can send information with WebSocket from frontend to backend, but can't send information from backend to frontend.

I'm right now trying to use WebSocket with ws lib, but I can't send information to frontend and I don't know why.

Please, someone help?

```js
// websocket.ts -- creating a websocket server
export async function createWebSocketServer(): Promise<typeof wss | undefined> {
  try {
    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
      clients.push(ws);
      ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log('Received from back: ', message.toLocaleString());
      });

      ws.on('close', () => {
        clients = clients.filter((client) => client !== ws);
      });
    });

    console.log('WebSocket server started on port 3005');

    return wss;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

```js
// /api/ml-pix/webhook -- my nextjs server. I use that line to send information to front-end, but doesnt work. Only ws lib can see that information.
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3005');

   ws.onopen = () => {
     ws.send(JSON.stringify(body));
     ws.close();
   };
```

```js
    // my frontend code with a websocket hook. 'data' comes from websocket hook.
    // this doesnt work. any messages was detected.
    useEffect(() => {
     if (open && readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
            
              return () => {
                if (readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                }
              };
            }, [readyState, open]);
```

I already try to use socket io, but is just too overengineer to my propus.

I'm right now trying to use WebSocket with ws lib, but I can't send information to frontend and I don't know why.